# AWS Serverless : Migrating from serverless to SAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, aws-sam

We are using Serverless framework for deploying our applications on AWS.
The applications are written using Lambda, Cognito, API gateway, DynamoDB,  etc.

We want make use of SAM local, as we want to test the applications locally ( with local DynamoDb) , before deploying to AWS Cloud.

Is there any simpler way, by which I can migrate my serverless.yml file to the yml file required by SAM?

I have a complex serverless.yml file ( API Gateway, custom and cognito authorizers, CORS, Lambda, DynamoDB, IAM roles and policies, IOT rules, S3 buckets and policies, etc.)  and creating a SAM template by hand will be complex.

I found one node.js plugin - https://github.com/sapessi/serverless-sam

Looks like this plugin, has some issues. It didn't migrate all parts of the serverless.yml file correctly.

The serverless.yml file deployment creates a Cloudformation template.

Can this template be used for generating SAM yml file? Or can this template be migrated or enhanced to the template needed by SAM?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your primary question, but have you tried the serverless-offline and serverless-dynamodb-local plugins to run your application locally?
https://serverless.com/plugins/serverless-dynamodb-local/
https://serverless.com/plugins/serverless-offline/

Comment: Thanks. I tried using serverless local. But every time, I invoke the API, I get an error - Proxy Handler could not detect JSON: END RequestId

Comment: @Dattatray I am getting "Proxy Handler could not detect JSON" when using serverless offline but they are more like warnings because they do not prevent functions to work properly.